# Guardar un libro de excel creado con el paquete xlsx de R en un bucket de S3 de AWS

Tags: r, aws, amazon-s3

Usando el paquete xlsx de R yo creé un libro de excel con mpultiples hojas a través del siguente código:

```
workbook_1 = xlsx::createWorkbook()
```

Que tiene la siguiente clase:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito subir ese libro de excel a una ruta de un bucket de S3. Intenté con el siguiente código:

```
s3write_using(workbook_1, object = paste0("file_location_path" + "workbook_1.xlsx" ), FUN=write.xlsx, bucket = "bucket_S3")
```

Pero obtengo el siguiente error:

[image]

Creo que  se debe a que my workbook no tiene una extensión .xlxs. Alguno de ustedes sabe cómo puedo convertir my archivo `workbook_1` a xlsx?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: ¡Hola! Como ya observaste, el resultado de createWorkbook() no es un achivo xlsx, sino una referencia de Java a otro objeto. La solución simple sería escribir tu libro de excel a un archivo y subir este al bucket ¿Hay una razón por la que no esto podría no ser posible?

Comment: Hola! En realidad, necesito subirlo directamente con código.  En este momento mi código guarda el workbook con extensión .xlsx  localmente en mi computador. La idea es que mi código no tenga rutas locales, para que pueda ser replicado por otra persona. Habría una forma de hacer que el workbook ya no sea una extensión de Java sino un .xlsx?

Comment: Una opción es crear un archivo temporal, con tempfile(), para almacenar tu libro de excel allí. Como el temporal se guarda en una ruta relativa específica para el usuario, evitaría el uso de rutas locales.